# Enforcing minimum number of observations before deciding state in HMM

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model

I am trying to model a state detection problem using HMMs (using pomegranate library in python but that is besides the point). One of the challenges I have when using Viterbi to decide the most likely state sequence is I need a minimum of observations to be present before I can accept the state.

For example, if I have two observations (0, 1) and 2 states (a, x) 
I would like to model,
for a sequence of observations 0101001010101, xxxxxxxxxxxxx and
for a sequence of observations 0011111111110, xxaaaaaaaaaax.
But right now with the transitions for observations 0101001010101, it gives xaxaxxaxaxaxa and tweaking transition probabilities to make it right is very cumbersome.

Any ideas or directions for how to model this will be appreciated.